# Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to perform web scraping using Python within MS SQL Server.  This is my code:

```
execute sp_execute_external_script @language = N'Python',
@script = N'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b

import requests as r

import pandas as p

myURL = ''https://www.skysports.com/f1/standings''

downloadURL = r.get(myURL, headers={''User-Agent'':''test''})

soup = b(downloadURL.text, "html.parser")

fullTable = soup.select(''tbody'')[0]
driver = fullTable.select(''a span'')

tableRows = []

for d in driver:
    tableRows.append(str(d).replace(''<span class="standing-table__cell--name-text">'','').replace(''</span>'','').strip())

df = p.DataFrame(tableRows, columns=[''DriverName''])

print(df)'
```

But I keep receiving the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

SqlSatelliteCall error: Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
SqlSatelliteCall function failed. Please see the console output for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.DATAWHSE\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\computecontext\RxInSqlServer.py", line 605, in rx_sql_satellite_call
    rx_native_call("SqlSatelliteCall", params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.DATAWHSE\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\revoscalepy\RxSerializable.py", line 375, in rx_native_call
    ret = px_call(functionname, params)
RuntimeError: revoscalepy function failed.
```

If I just run the Python code in Visual Studio code it works fine - what am I missing?

I have looked in other forums and have patched to SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU15) (KB5008996), but this did not fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could it be related to the string delimiters? In the `str.replace` function call the empty string is `''` but the other strings are delimited with `''string''` (which I presume is due to escaping). In others words, shouldn't the empty string be `''''` (4 no. `'`)?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin yes of course! this has worked. silly me, thank you

Comment: You should probably use a proper HTML parser

Comment: @Charlieface how do you mean?

Comment: Instead of `str(d).replace(''<span class="standing-table__cell--name-text">'','').replace(''</span>'','')` you can just do something like `d.string` or `d.content` to get the inner text. Not that familiar with BeautifulSoup but can't imagine it's too difficult

Comment: Also what is `print(df)` supposed to do? If you want to return the data to SQL Server you need an output table, see the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15